# Django CMS Draft/Live system for custom model

Tags: django, django-cms

Django CMS has cool Draft/Live -system related to pages. Does Django CMS support enabling similar functionality for custom models? If it does how to do it?

I'm trying to build news-app, that have models, that have placeholderfield and some other fields.

So, any ideas how to implement draft/live -system for my news-app?

Django-CMS 3.0.0
Django 1.5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the way draft/live system implemented in Django CMS doesn't allow to reuse it on another model. In Django CMS, it is [achieved](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/models/pagemodel.py#L92) by versioning Page object and maintaining `publisher_is_draft` and `publisher_public` properties.

Yet you can't directly reuse Django CMS approach in your app, you can closely reimplement it in your own, better way. Please don't forget to share the sources :)

Answer (score 1):

We actually want that 3rd party apps can have a daft/public version workflow easily... if you could come up with a way to provide that.... please share.